# Pulling RGB24 signal out directly instead of LVDS interface

Tags: interface, rgb, hdmi, lvds

I am designing a display driver board. I have used a HDMI receiver ADV7619 for the same, I am using HDMI input to my board coming from PC. This receiver has RGB and YCrCb signal out. I have already defined an LVDS interface.

My question is, can i take RGB24 signal out from this receiver directly instead of using LVDS interface which I think here is not necessary.

Is it possible to interface the LVDS pinout directly to this IC.

Below I have pasted the LVDS interface that I have defined for my project. the additional pins for e.g. backlight can be ignored. The important pins  are LVDS differential pairs.

**LVDS Interface**

1. RXO0-   -lvds chan0-odd
2. RXO0+   +lvds chan0-odd
3. RXO1-   -lvds chan 1-odd
4. RXO1+   +lvds chan 1-odd
5. RXO2-   -lvds chan 2-odd
6. RXO2+   +lvds chan 2-odd
7. vss ground
8. RXOC-   -lvds chan Clock input odd
9. RXOC+   +lvds Clock input odd
10. RXO3-   -lvds chan 3-odd
11. RXO3+   +lvds chan 3-odd
12. RXE0-   -lvds chan 0-odd
13. RXE0+   +lvds chan 0-odd
14. vss ground
15. RXE1-   -lvds chan 1-even
16. RXE1+   +lvds chan 1-odd
17. vss     ground
18. RXE2-   -lvds chan 2-odd
19. RXE2+   +lvds chan 2-odd
20. RXEC-   +lvds chan Clock even
21. RXEC+   +lvds chan Clock even
22. RXE3-   -lvds chan 3-odd
23. RXE3+   +lvds chan 3-odd
24. vss ground
25. vss ground
26. NC  not connected
27. AGMODE  aging mode selection
28. Vcc +5V power supply
29. Vcc +5V power supply
30. Vcc +5V power supply
31. Vcc +3.3V power supply
32. Bklt_power  backlight power
33. bklt_pwr    backlight_power
34. bklt_pwr    backlight_power
35. bklt_gnd    ground
36. bklt_gnd    ground
37. bklt_gnd    ground
38. I2c_gnd i2c_ground
39. i2c_sda i2c_sda
40. i2c_ pwr    i2c_power
41. i2c_scl i2c_scl
42. bklt_pwr    backlight power
43. bklt_pwr    backlight power
44. bklt_pwr    backlight power
45. bklt_gnd    ground
46. bklt_gnd    ground
47. bklt_gnd    ground
48. bklt_enable     Enable BLK pin
49. GND
50. GND
51. GND
52. GND
53. GND
54. GND
55. GND
56. GND
57. GND
58. GND
59. GND
60. GND

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: LVDS signal description https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla014a/snla014a.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Doing a text search for 'LVDS' on this datasheet turns up nothing, so I am going with "No."

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same before. But I think the signal conversion is needed

Comment: LVDS encodings can be tricky and vary a bit, so there would need to be a lot of configurability inside the device. When you wire up an LVDS encoder chip you know what signals are going where, which is good.